# Ordering a DateTime's components based on culture

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Say I have a DateTime object that represents today's date at midnight (2017-08-02 00:00:00.000)

I want to take that object and present it in a user-readable way that contains the day of month, day of week and month.

In North America it's my understanding it would be formatted like this:

> Monday, July 2

In Norwegian, however, it would look like this:

> Mandag 2. juli

As you can see, the day of month and month has switched places, there's no comma after "Monday", and a period has been added after the 2 to indicate that it's an ordinal.

Is there a way in .NET (or some library like NodaTime) to get this kind of formatting out of the box, or will I have to hard-code it for each language our app supports?

Comment: You will possible have to look at switching the "locale" in code depending on what language is being used for your application. See here for reference; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631825.aspx

Comment: Each culture has it's own DateTime format. For your app, you can build your own format with calling the `.ToString(format)` method of the DateTime with the desired format as the parameter.

Comment: I'd have thought just calling [`ToLongDateString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) should be sufficient, and let culture settings take control of the appearance.

Comment: @SQLAndOtherStuffGuy Yeah, we can switch locale, but I was wondering if there was something like this exact format available out of the box without having to write our own format like Ian H. suggests.

Comment: @PetterBrodin Would it be a problem when the year is included?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever looks like it might make sense to use ToLongDateString but remove the year from the end, provided all cultures put the year at the end.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom, the year is already known in this particular context, so to save space in the UI it's desirable to display the formatted date without the year.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever looks like that will require more coding, at least, since Mexican Spanish (for example) adds " de 2017" to the end: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#LongDate

Comment: @PetterBrodin and sometimes the year is separated with a comma as well ;)

Comment: I wouldn't like to assert either way whether there are any cultures where there's no way to present a day/month combination without a year and it being generally understood. I try not to make too many assumptions on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [standard format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) for dates to get some predefined formattings that are culture specific when calling `yourDate.ToString(<formatStringHere>)`. The one that is nearest to your requirement would be the "D" format string, but it does include the year.

The `yourDate.ToLongDateString()` would be another way to get this format.

If it's possible that the `,` between the day and the other part can be ignored or can always be present, you could combine the `"M"` format string which gives you the month/day format with the `"dddd"` custom format which gives you the day name.

```
var dateString = $"{yourDate.ToString("dddd")}, {yourDate.ToString("M")}"
```

But I'm not aware of a fitting, out of the box format for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern.aspx) to get the long date format and remove the year part.

For example:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2017, 01, 10);
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
string s = culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
s = s.Replace("y", "");
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(s));
```

Though in doing so you could get some strange outputs. This will output:

`Tuesday, January 10,`